# ¿Cómo puedo convertir datos tipo fecha (ejemplo"2022-04-30" o "30/04/2022") a texto para que muestre "30 de abril del 2022"? PHP o JS

Tags: javascript, php, date

El problema es que mi código muestra los datos de la base de datos en forma de números, y los usuarios se suelen confundir, entonces antes de mostrarlos el código los convierta a formato de texto entendible para usuarios.
Gracias

Comment: y donde quieres realizar esa conversión?  en PHP o en javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando javascript:

```js
let date = new Date("2022-04-30".replace(/-/g, "/"));
let options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("es", options));
```

Si no precisas el día de la semana, simplemente remueve el `weekday`:

```js
let date = new Date("2022-04-30".replace(/-/g, "/"));
let options = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("es", options));
```

Comment: +1 Esta es la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2022-04-30');
echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');

?>
```

No recuerdo bien el formato de Año/mes/dia o si es viceversa con el mes.

Answer (score 0):

La forma de la que lo hago yo, es usar la libreria de javascript moment de la siguiente forma:

```
var fecha = "04-06-2022"
//Transformo objeto moment y doy formato
moment(fecha).format('LL')
//fecha =  April 6, 2022
```

Segun la documentacion de moment se puede traducir las fechas a espanol, a mi no me funciono.. entonces cree una funcion para traducir el moment y me quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
//Traducir el mes de una fecha en-es
function traducirMoment(fecha) {
let mes = moment(fecha).format("MMMM")
switch (mes) {
    case "January":
        mest = "Enero"
        break
    case "February":
        mest = "Febrero"
        break
    case "March":
        mest = "Marzo"
        break
    case "April":
        mest = "Abril"
        break
    case "May":
        mest = "Mayo"
        break
    case "June":
        mest = "Junio"
        break
    case "July":
        mest = "Julio"
        break
    case "August":
        mest = "Agosto"
        break
    case "September":
        mest = "Septiembre"
        break
    case "October":
        mest = "Octubre"
        break
    case "November":
        mest = "Noviembre"
        break
    case "December":
        mest = "Diciembre"
        break
    default:
        mest = mes;
    break
}
return fecha.replace(mes, mest) 
}
//Salida = Abril 6,2022
```

Te dejo la documentación de moment.js en el siguiente enlace [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)
Es una libreria que te permite dar diferentes formatos a las fechas, te permite calcular rangos entre fechas en meses,dias,anios.. etc.. recomendadisima